# Why can't this Android app cast text from Firebase into strings?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I made a simple Android app that is supposed to display text from Firebase. Yet, I have an issue converting Firebase data into strings. Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private Firebase ref;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("xxx");
    final TextView textbox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textbox);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String newCon = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            textbox.setText(newCon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
  }
}
```

I get these errors:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at com.example.elish_000.myfirstapp.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:43)
```

There are no errors when I run the app. Yet, when I add text to Firebase the app crashes instead of displaying the text.

Comment: Did you **read** the errormessage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase returns a `HashMap` by default to represent a JSON object. You're probably looking for one of the `String` properties within that object.

There's two ways to handle this.

#### 1 - Use a `HashMap` and extract the key.

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   HashMap<String, Object> data = dataSnapshot.getValue();
   String newCon = data.get("newCon");
   textbox.setText(newCon);
}
```

#### 2 - Create a type-safe class, and deserialize the Firebase data to the object.

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   MyClass theObject = snapshot.getValue(MyClass.class);
   textbox.setText(theObject.newCon);
}
```

#### I highly recommend option 2!

Deserializing to a class may take *a little bit more* upfront. But, it pays huge dividends of type-safety and code readability.

Here are some docs for retrieving data with Firebase. 
https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html